# Regular Expression for splitting string

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for regular expression to get the match as `"HELLO"` and `"WORLD"` separately when the input is any of the following:

```
"HELLO", "WORLD"
"HELL"O"", WORLD"
"HELL,O","WORLD"
```

I have tried few combination but none of them seem to work for all the scenarios.

I am looking to have my c# code perform something like this:

```
string pattern = Regex Pattern;
// input here could be any one of the strings given above
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
   // first iteration would give me Hello
   // second iteration would give me World
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only require it on Hello and World I suggest Sebastian's Answer.  It is a perfect approach to this.  If you really are putting other data in there, and don't want to capture Hello and World.

Here is another solution:

^([A-Z\"\,]+)[\"\,\s]+([A-Z\"\,]+)$

The only thing is, this will return HELLO and WORLD with the " and , in it.

Then it us up to you to do a replace " and , to nothing in the output strings.

Example:

```
//RegEx: ^([A-Z\"\,]+)[\"\,\s]+([A-Z\"\,]+)$
    string pattern = "^([A-Z\"\\,]+)[\"\\,\\s]+([A-Z\"\\,]+)$";
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex Reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

    string MyInput;

    MyInput = "\"HELLO\",\"WORLD\"";
    MyInput = "\"HELL\"O\"\",WORLD\"";
    MyInput = "\"HELL,O\",\"WORLD\"";

    string First;
    string Second;

    if (Reg.IsMatch(MyInput))
    {
        string[] result;
        result = Reg.Split(MyInput);

        First = result[1].Replace("\"","").Replace(",","");
        Second = result[2].Replace("\"","").Replace(",","");
    }
```

First and Second would be Hello and World.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"^WORLD|HELL[""|O|,]?O[""|O|,]$").Success
```

Comment: It's an answer to the question. This is a problem many programmers have, they answer the user, but the user did not know how to address the programmer. My brain says "42".

Answer (score 0):

I always found it useful to use an online Regular Expression tester like this one http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/.